# How to Re-size Images that are Too Large on-the-fly with Paperclip and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to implement the steps to check and resize images with paperclip based on this blog post: http://www.techdarkside.com/how-to-re-size-images-that-are-too-large-on-the-fly-with-paperclip-and-rails

Here is what I have in place...

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  # subclasses
  class Question::Image < Asset
    has_attached_file :attachment,
                      :url => "/uploads/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:basename_:style.:extension",
                      :styles => Proc.new { |attachment| attachment.instance.styles },
                      :styles => Proc.new { |attachment| attachment.instance.resize }
                        attr_accessible :attachment
    # http://www.ryanalynporter.com/2012/06/07/resizing-thumbnails-on-demand-with-paperclip-and-rails/
    def dynamic_style_format_symbol
        URI.escape(@dynamic_style_format).to_sym
      end

      def styles
        unless @dynamic_style_format.blank?
          { dynamic_style_format_symbol => @dynamic_style_format }
        else
          { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
        end
      end

      def dynamic_attachment_url(format)
        @dynamic_style_format = format
        attachment.reprocess!(dynamic_style_format_symbol) unless attachment.exists?(dynamic_style_format_symbol)
        attachment.url(dynamic_style_format_symbol)
      end

      def resize
        if self.attachment_file_size > 2000000
          "300x300>"
        else
          " "
        end
      end
    end
```

I'm thinking the issue is with the reuse of the `:styles` symbol, however I'm not sure how to work both the styles method AND the resize method into a single Proc statement.

Comment: Yes, Ruby hashes cannot have the same key multiple times. How about leaving the second one out, and changing `{ :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }` to `{ :medium => resize, :thumb => "100x100>" }`?

Comment: It's possible that `attachment_file_size` — the attribute on `Question` isn't set at that moment yet. Try replacing `self.attachment_file_size` with `attachment.size`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with thanks to @janfoeh suggestion. I did need to add `:original`to the options in style to get this to work. I also bumped the max file size up to 5mb.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  # subclasses
  class Question::Image < Asset
    has_attached_file :attachment,
                      :url => "/uploads/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:basename_:style.:extension",
                      :styles => Proc.new { |attachment| attachment.instance.styles }
    attr_accessible :attachment

    # http://www.ryanalynporter.com/2012/06/07/resizing-thumbnails-on-demand-with-paperclip-and-rails/
    def dynamic_style_format_symbol
        URI.escape(@dynamic_style_format).to_sym
    end

    def styles
      unless @dynamic_style_format.blank?
        { dynamic_style_format_symbol => @dynamic_style_format }
      else
        { :original => resize, :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
      end
    end

    def dynamic_attachment_url(format)
      @dynamic_style_format = format
      attachment.reprocess!(dynamic_style_format_symbol) unless attachment.exists?(dynamic_style_format_symbol)
      attachment.url(dynamic_style_format_symbol)
    end

    def resize
      if self.attachment_file_size > 5000000
        "1000x1000>"
      else
        " "
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: If you're concerned about file sizes, take a look at my [paperclip-optimizer](https://github.com/janfoeh/paperclip-optimizer) gem as well. Minifying images can significantly slim them down.